# getline() with ifstream pointer error?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void Category:: fillCategories(char** & categories, char** &subset, std::ifstream *input, 
int*&subIndex)
{
    while(!input->eof())
    {
        char buffer[30];
        if (getCatSize()==getCatCapacty())
        {
            resize(categories, getCategoryCapAddress(), 5);
        }
        if (getSubSize()==getSubCap())
        {
            resize(subset, getSubsetCapAddress(), 5, subIndex);
        }
        std::getline(*input,buffer);
    }
}
```

for some reason

```
std::getline(*input,buffer);
```

is giving me an error. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: `std::getline` can't be used with a character array. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong about why your `while` expression is wrong.

Comment: Pass your streams by reference.

Comment: Read the error.  If you need to, share the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `getline` up into the loop condition, and replace `while` with `for`, like this:

```
for (std::string buffer; getline(*input, buffer); )
```

And of course remove the `char[]` version of `buffer`.  This way you have a dynamically sized `buffer` that works with `std::getline` and uses the correct termination condition.